# Using fit() with conditions for the first derivative

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

Is it possible to fit a curve through some points and apply a condition for the resulting fit?

I want the **first derivative** of the fit to have a certain **value**(force) at x=0.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
options = fitoptions;
options.Weights = [1000,1000,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
myfittype = fittype('(exp(g*x))*(a*(x^5) + b*(x^4) + c*(x^3) + d*(x^2) + e*(x) + f)','coeff',{'g','a','b','c','d','f'},'problem',{'e'});
[moment_fit,gof1] = fit(xdata_fit',momentarray1',myfittype,'problem',{-force});
[shear_fit_values,soilrctn_fit_values] = differentiate(moment_fit,points');
```

Previously before introducing the exponential in the custom equation I used to force the derivative of the function to be a certain value by controlling one of the coefficients as you can see above (if its a 5th degree polynomial without exponential, the value of e is the derivative of the function at 0).

Is it possible? I have done the calculations on hand and the condition that has to be placed on the coefficients is `g*f + e = force`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just manually calculate the derivative and plug the coefficients in?

```
myfit_derivative =@(x) exp(myfittype.g .* x) .* (myfittype.f.*myfittype.g + myfittype.e.*(1+myfittype.g.*x)+myfittype.d.*(2.*x+myfittype.g.*x^2)+myfittype.c.*(3.*x^2+myfittype.g.*x^3)+myfittype.b.*(4.*x^3+myfittype.g.*x^4)+myfittype.a.*(5.*x^4+myfittype.g.*x^5));
```

Comment: I dont understand what you did there, could you explain the code please? Whats the @x?

Comment: So the code you wrote is the derivative which I know how to formulate. I want that equation to be a certain value at x = 0. Can I force this while I am fitting the original equation?

Comment: This is the problem with fitting. Is there any physical / mathematical reasoning behind these coefficients? Because there are a large infinity of solutions to this otherwise

Comment: The fit() function fits the data fine with a good looking curve. The issue is I have a known point that I am certain of. But this known value is in the derivative of the equation. This was easy to do when my custom equation was a simple 5th degree polynomial. I just used to control the 'e' constant to my liking which results in the derivative having that value at x =0. But when I introduced the exponential it became alot tougher to determine which constants to restrain and to what value. Thats what Im asking for, is there a way to do it without having to determine the derivative mathematically

Comment: Okay, well can you fit with an `exp` * third order polynomial and get a good result? Or a first, second, or third order polynomial (since the `exp` will drive one side to 0)? Because you are talking about a force, so is there some sort of model behind that?

Comment: I could try that, I think the 5th degree should be enough since finding a solution will be hard if I want to add the exponential to the 5th degree. I am currently stuck at trying to find the double integral of the equation I fit my data. Do I have to do it manually? The integrate() function returns a number not a function like the differentiate.

Comment: You can use `integral2` (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html). I still am stuck on the fact that you are not letting your understanding of the physics at work inform your model.